# Microsoft Oxfordproject Speech-to-text Rest API

Tags: api, rest, speech, azure-cognitive-services

I need to recognize speech to text with Microsoft engines via Rest API (I know about other speech to text engines and I have them working, but now I need exactly MS speech-to-text).

I read a lot of info and manuals but cannot get it working.

I tried to follow the manuals from MS site (sorry I cannot add more links) but no luck, then I found many "working" examples, and find another way how to recognize via MS API, but stack with the problem:

1) I can get token to authorize recognition request:

[image: issue token request]

2) After I have the token, I can try to make a request to recognize the recording:

[image: Request to recognize the audio recording]

But in any case I will get the error.
Despite the "version" is set in the request.

If anyone knows how to recognize audio recordings via Microsoft Rest API service please give me example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be sure but the screenshot makes it look like `version` and other parameters were in the form (payload), but the spec requires these to be query parameters instead.

Comment: It doesn't matter, if I move all parameters to query 

I will get
`Parameter 'samplerate' value is null.
Parameter name: samplerate `
- despite it's set in header


Then if I add samplerate to request value I will get
`Parameter 'mimetype' value 'multipart/form-data' is invalid.
Parameter name: mimetype
`
...

Comment: can you share example working through Rest API 

or any working example

Comment: Basically all the arguments are query parameters. I wrote a bash script.  Depending on your OS, you'll want to roll a different getuuid method:
```function getuuid() {
   echo `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-f0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1 |  perl -ne 'print join("-", /(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})/);'`
}
curl -v "https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize/query?version=3.0&requestId=$(getuuid)&appID=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&format=json&locale=en-US&device.os=Windows+OS&scenarios=ulm&instanceid=$(getuuid)" \
-H "Content-Type: audio/wav; samplerate=8000" \

Comment: ```-H "Authorization: Bearer $speech_token" \
--data-binary @your.wav```

Comment: Thank you so much

curl example is absolutely what I needed, and It works.